# Why use hex values instead of normal base 10 numbers?

Tags: java, c, hex, math.sqrt

I was looking over [this code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-math1/index.html?ca=dgr-btw03JavaPart1&S_Tact=105AGX59&S_cmp=GRsitebtw03#hypotenuse) to calculate `math.sqrt` in Java.  Why did they use hex values in some of the loops and normal values for variables?  What benefits are there to use hex?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because hex corresponds much more closely to bits that decimal numbers. Each hex digit corresponds to 4 bits (a nibble). So, once you've learned the bitmask associated with each hex digit (0-F), you can do something like "I want a mask for the low order byte":

```
0xff
```

or, "I want a mask for the bottom 31 bits":

```
0x7fffffff
```

Just for reference:

```
HEX    BIN
0   -> 0000
1   -> 0001
2   -> 0010
3   -> 0011
4   -> 0100
5   -> 0101
6   -> 0110
7   -> 0111
8   -> 1000
9   -> 1001
A   -> 1010
B   -> 1011
C   -> 1100
D   -> 1101
E   -> 1110
F   -> 1111
```

Answer (score 3):

They probably used hex values because the numbers are easier to remember in hex. For example, 0x7fffffff is the same as 2147483647, but is a lot easier to remember.

Answer (score 2):

Hex is a human readable form of the binary the CPU actually uses. When looking at low level commands it often makes more sense to match the CPU and think in hex,