# What are benefits of using Hexadecimal notation?

Tags: c++, hex, long-integer

Recently, Google published some hash functions on [Github](https://github.com/google/highwayhash). On this functions codes, some values are defined on base 16, for example on [scalar_highway_tree_hash.cc](https://github.com/google/highwayhash/blob/master/scalar_highway_tree_hash.cc) we have:

```
 const Lanes init0 = {0xdbe6d5d5fe4cce2full, 0xa4093822299f31d0ull,
                     0x13198a2e03707344ull, 0x243f6a8885a308d3ull};
```

`0xdbe6d5d5fe4cce2full` is a hexadecimal `unsigned long long` integer that is equal to `15845587454020866000` on base 10.

Now i have this question: Why we use this notation instead of writing value in direct decimal representation? Expect the shorter string, is there any other reason for using this manner?

Comment: What is *"direct"* about decimal? It's really a *binary* somewhere.

Comment: Each hexadecimal digit represents the same number of bits. Might make it easier to "see" the binary result.

Comment: If you've got a value that you're using as a bitmask it's often much easier to see which bits that are set in hexadecimal notation compared to decimal notation. E.g. 0xF0FF vs 61695.

Comment: [Why do Computers use Hex Number System at assembly language?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24198530/995714), [Importance of Hexadecimal numbers in Computer Science](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16513806/995714), [Why use hex values instead of normal base 10 numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/451886/995714), [Why are flag enums usually defined with hexadecimal values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13222671/995714)

Comment: Hex (base 16) is a multiple of 8. Thus two hex digits represent one byte. As others allready said its easier to see the bitmask this way.

Comment: I know that there are only different representation of one thing, but I want to know situations of using each representation. @BoPersson

Comment: Links helped me, thanks. @LưuVĩnhPhúc

Comment: @MarioDeken *Non sequitur.* Octal is also a multiple of 8 but it doesn't have that property.

Comment: @EJP Well that was not the exact relation. To be correct: 8 is a multiple of log2(16). log2(16) equals 4. This means one hex digit represents 4 binary digits. Thus, you need 8/4=2 hex digits for one byte. For octal: log2(8) equals 3. Its still an even number meaning you can directly read octal as binary as well (one octal digit equals 3 binary digits). But since 3 is not a multiple of 8 you cant fill a byte. In general: A number with base a can fully represent n digits in base b if logb(a) | n is true. Quod erat demonstrandum :D